# Is there a better way to convert a String array to an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, io

I use the following code each time I need an integer array:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ");
int[] a =new int[str.length];
int j = 0;
for(String i : str)
  a[j++]=Integer.parseInt(i);
```

I use BufferedReader instead of Scanner to reduce the time complexity during input. However I wonder whether this method is efficient than Scanner when the array size is relatively larger(>100). In such cases, is there a better way to convert a String array to an integer array ?

Comment: What do you mean, "reduce the time complexity"?  `Scanner` will have the same asymptotics and competitive constant factors.

Comment: While calculating the time complexity of a program we mostly rely on the number of loops and virtually take everything for constant. I/O methods make a big difference. Try a problem with Scanner and then with BufferedReader, check their execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With java 8, it's pretty straightforward, and only one line:

```
int[] a = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) performs better than calling `split`. After that I convert the tokens into ints the same way you do. I think this is the best performing method to input a series of many integers printed on a single line. Here is a [thread](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/6834) where different approaches are discussed and measured.

Also I would like to point out that this is the approach used by most programming competitors such as the legend Petr Mitrichev, thus I believe it is as good as you can get.